# Append timestamp to a S3 bucket folder in builspec.yaml file

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-codepipeline

I am new to YAML file. I want to append Timestamp to S3 bucket folder every time so that each build will be unique. In the post_build I append timestamp to S3 bucket as follows. When the codepipeline is triggered all files are stored to S3 bucket Inhouse folder but folder with timestamp is not getting generated. s3://${S3_BUCKET}/Inhouse/${'date'}

```
Version: 0.2
env:
    variables:
        S3_BUCKET: Inhouse-market-dev
phases:
    install:
        runtime-versions:
            nodejs: 10
        commands:
            - npm install
            - npm install -g @angular/cli
    build:
        commands:
            - echo Build started on `date`
    post_build:
         commands:
            - aws s3 cp . s3://${S3_BUCKET}/Inhouse/${'date'} --recursive --acl public-read --cache-control "max-age=${CACHE_CONTROL}"
            - echo Build completed on `date`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your use of `${'date'}` is incorrect. I would recommend trying the following to actually get the unix timestamp:

```
    post_build:
         commands:
            - current_timestamp=$(date +"%s")
            - aws s3 cp . s3://${S3_BUCKET}/Inhouse/${current_timestamp} --recursive --acl public-read --cache-control "max-age=${CACHE_CONTROL}"
            - echo Build completed on `date` which is ${current_timestamp}
```

Comment: Hey Marcin. It worked. I got the mistake thanks for your help.

Comment: @RaghuRam Glad to hear that. If so, acceptance of the answer would be appreciated. Thanks.